# How to properly unit test constexpr functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, constexpr

If I have a `constexpr` function, should there be both a runtime verification, and a compile time verification?

If there is only a compile-time check `static_assert`, then the function will not be included in any code coverage statistics. However, if there is only a runtime check, there is no verification that the function actually works in a `constexpr` context.

In short, the question is whether or not both runtime unit-testing *and* `static_assert`s are needed to test the same thing.

Comment: Sorry but isn't clear to me what do you exactly want. Can you explain better? Can you add an example?

Comment: The purpose of `constexpr` is to tell the compiler that the value can be calculated during *compilation* time. So, the actual value might be different only if changes happened *before* compilation - (for ex: switching between Debug/Release/etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already there

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195282/constexpr-unit-tests-and-asserts

```
// assertion checking failure
inline constexpr auto your_assert_data(bool isOkay, std::string_view message)
{
    if (!isOkay)
        throw std::logic_error{message};
}
```

according to your question there is no anything you have tried 
so look at this also

https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/06/27/use-constexpr-for-faster-smaller-and-safer-code/

Comment: I have read that post. What I am asking about is that if you desire to collect some test coverage, you will not get anything from `static_asserts`, because no code was ever executed. So the question is whether or not to do both runtime test, and compile time test. The former to be able to collect coverage data, the latter to verify that everything really is `constexpr`.